# ga4 how to make dataRetentionSettings request

Tags: python, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I recently started working with ga4 and followed the samples [Here](https://github.com/googleapis/python-analytics-data/blob/main/samples/snippets/quickstart.py). I can make dimension and metric queries with it but now i want to make request just like [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/admin/v1/rest/v1beta/properties/getDataRetentionSettings?hl=en) (for properties.getDataRetentionSettings). How can i make this request in python?

I also found the [source code](https://googleapis.dev/python/analyticsadmin/latest/_modules/google/analytics/admin_v1alpha/types/analytics_admin.html)   but i couldn't find a sample for making a ga4 request other than dimension and metrics.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the dimensions and metrics from `Data API`. Which is use for getting data like a report.

If you want to get the setting from the GA4 property or account. You need to use the `Admin API`

Here is the sample from all python ga4 admin API

https://github.com/googleapis/python-analytics-admin/tree/main/samples

I found there is one sample but not verified from my end

https://github.com/googleapis/python-analytics-admin/blob/380b4264003b17b802b7099b98837694cd0b87d1/samples/generated_samples/analyticsadmin_v1alpha_generated_analytics_admin_service_get_data_retention_settings_sync.py

But be careful when using `Admin API`. It might change the setting or delete the property in the worst case maybe.